# Reading binary file. ReadAllBytes() array size different than file size

Tags: c#, file, binary, hex

I have a binary file with a custom formatting that I need to parse and extract information from.

When I open the file with a **Hex editor**, it shows **675 bytes** in the file, and the file size in its windows properties windows is also **675 bytes(Size on disk: 4KB)**.

When I use the C# method `File.ReadAllBytes()`, I get an array of size **1172 bytes**.

I cannot make any sense of the bytes present in the array with respect to the bytes in the Hex editor.

Why does C# read in **1172 bytes** when the file contains **675 bytes**? How can I parse this?

Comment: Could you post your code and ideally the file as well?

Comment: I'm just using `byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(fullFilePath);` and using a breakpoint to look at its size. byteArray size is 1172. 
The file is proprietary, I cannot share sorry :(

Comment: Try using BinaryReader
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Open))

Comment: Are you sure that you point to the correct file?

Comment: Probably you are passing the wrong `fullFilePath`. `File.ReadAllBytes` "works", so it must be your code around the `File.ReadAllBytes` that doesn't work. In the debugger try `new FileInfo(fullFilePath).Length` and see the length that it shows you

Comment: there is no problem with ReadAllBytes.i think your file path is wrong

Comment: Okay... two files with the same name and different extensions(which are similar). My bad guys, wrong file name. Sorry for wasting your time.
Thanks.